# TFS 2012 has additional work item type fields after export

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-workitem

I have exported the work item type definition for "Bugs" from my TFS2012 team project (using power tools). Then I've compared the generated XML with the original definition of the project template - Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.2 - downloaded with the Process Template Manager.

I found several differences. I have an explaination for the most of them except the following additional fields:

```
  <FIELD name="Iteration ID" refname="System.IterationId" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="External Link Count" refname="System.ExternalLinkCount" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Team Project" refname="System.TeamProject" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Hyperlink Count" refname="System.HyperLinkCount" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Attached File Count" refname="System.AttachedFileCount" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Node Name" refname="System.NodeName" type="String" />
  <FIELD name="Revised Date" refname="System.RevisedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="detail" />
  <FIELD name="Changed Date" refname="System.ChangedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="ID" refname="System.Id" type="Integer" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Area ID" refname="System.AreaId" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Authorized As" refname="System.AuthorizedAs" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" />
  <FIELD name="Authorized Date" refname="System.AuthorizedDate" type="DateTime" />
  <FIELD name="Watermark" refname="System.Watermark" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Rev" refname="System.Rev" type="Integer" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Changed By" refname="System.ChangedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Work Item Type" refname="System.WorkItemType" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Created Date" refname="System.CreatedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Created By" refname="System.CreatedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" />
  <FIELD name="Description" refname="System.Description" type="HTML" />
  <FIELD name="Related Link Count" refname="System.RelatedLinkCount" type="Integer" />
  <FIELD name="Tags" refname="System.Tags" type="PlainText" />
```

Why there are the files in the project template even it is not defined in the original package?

Comment: This doesn't seem correct, things in System should be on all Work Items. For example, I find it hard to believe that `ID` and `Rev` (revision / version) are missing, these are the two most fundamental parts of a Work Item.

Comment: Yes, I agree, these fields shall be available. But in the XML files available after download "ID" and "Rev" are not available. This is why I'm asking for an explaination of the difference.

Answer (score 2):

System fields are defined for each work item type whether they are explicitly defined in the work item type definition.